# Incorrect syntax near BEGIN when creating multi statement user-defined function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to recreate PostgreSQL `generate_series` function in SQL Server for `DATE` type like below

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.generateDatesBetween(@startdate DATE, @enddate DATE)
RETURNS TABLE (date DATE)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @res TABLE(date DATE);
    WHILE @startdate <= @enddate
        BEGIN
            INSERT @res(date) VALUES(@startdate)
            SET @startdate = DATEADD(DAY,1,@startdate)
        END;
    RETURN @res
END;
```

But it keeps showing this error

> [S0001][156] Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BEGIN'

I've tried to create many functions before this, but it works just fine with `BEGIN` keyword.

Anyone know how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: Why have you not checked the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) instead of asking a question here? As an aside that is going to perform really badly... why not use a tally table?

Comment: Who say that I haven't checked documentation? I've read some but still can't find the answer. I know it's going to perform badly but I didn't have choices. Anyway, thanks for showing me tally table!

Comment: Well the documentation is very clear on how you create a multi-line table valued function.

Comment: okay I find it, thanks Mr. Smart!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the function like below to make it work. You cannot have the table variable with RETURN keyword in Table valued user defined function. You can do that only in the scalar user defined function.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.generateDatesBetween(@startdate DATE, @enddate DATE)
RETURNS @res TABLE(date DATE)
AS BEGIN
    WHILE @startdate <= @enddate
        BEGIN
            INSERT @res(date) VALUES(@startdate)
            SET @startdate = DATEADD(DAY,1,@startdate)
        END;
    RETURN;
END;
```

Comment: Hi, can you show me which part in documentation that fix my problem? thanks!

Comment: @fahmiduldul, different ways of multi statement Table valued function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15#TVF